# django prefetch_related on multiple models

Tags: sql, django, django-models, django-orm

I have models like this

```
Model Trip:
  hotel: m2m_field to Hotel
  flight: m2m_field to Flight
Model Hotel:
  city: foreignkey to City
Model Flight:
  city: foreignkey to City
```

The problem is when I do

```
Trip.objects.prefetch_related('hotel__city', 'flight__city')
```

It generates 5 sql queries: 1 on Trip, 1 on Hotel, 1 on Flight, 1 on City from Hotel result, and 1 on City from Flight result. Can I reduce the last two queries on City table into 1? I think I may be asking too much from ORM, but just want to know whether it's possible either in ORM or raw-query.

Answer (score 1):

prefetch_related will always perform separate queries - from the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.prefetch_related):

> prefetch_related(**lookups) - Returns a QuerySet that will automatically retrieve, in a single batch, related objects for each of the specified lookups.

If you're looking to combine queries, you should be using [select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#select-related), which in this instance will perform a single query with four joins to the hotel, flight & city(x2) tables.